# gaining access to objects stored in Tag

Tags: vb.net, listview

I'm storing objects of type FileInfo and trying to regain access to them properly via a ListView.

I'm trying to make the full path dynamic.. but only displaying the filename in the listview.  So I gave a shot at storing the FileInfo in the tag but cannot regain the value.

this is how I place my info in the ListViews..

```
 For Each element As FileInfo In arrayList
            With ListView2
                .Items.Add(element.Name)
                .Tag = element
            End With
```

Now I want to regain access to the elements in the listview that are checked.  I can easily get the value displayed. but I'm only displaying the FileName and extension.  I want the full path.

```
 Private Sub ListView1_ItemCheck1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemCheck

Dim Path As String = Me.ListView1.Items(e.Index).Text
'this gives me the filename.. but I want to pull the full path out..
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get you the path:

```
Dim Path As String = CType(Me.ListView1.Items(e.Index).Tag, FileInfo).FullName
```

Or, if you want to access more properties than just the path, it would be useful to declare a `FileInfo` variable and set it to the tag:

```
Dim element As FileInfo = CType(Me.ListView1.Items(e.Index).Tag, FileInfo)
Dim Path As String = element.FullName
Dim fileName As String = element.Name
' ...
```

Comment: for some awkward reason I'm getting nothing in the string values after running.. I'm debugging now.  Now I can get a value from ListView.tag. but it's not the right value when the Listview checked box changes.

Comment: It's not magic.  If the value of the `Tag` property changes, it's only ever because you changed it.  Either that property changed, or it's an entirely new list item with a different tag.  I'd double check your other code and make sure you aren't altering the list elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I really scanned it up down.. and I could not find anything touching the tag value.. (very awkward).  Now since I was filling the listview in the same sequence as the array of FileInfo objects I just grabbed the FileInfo object at location (e.Index).  Not how I wanted it work.. but it does, until I figure out what's going on.